# Is controller with more flash memory consume more energy

Tags: controller, flash-memory, energy

I have this questionn. Is controller wirh more flash memory consume more enrgy power from controller with less flash memory from type and every other parameter is equal. The question is theoretical. I would ask the same for RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the higher density (capacity) memories are made with a smaller (ie 14nm) process, where the smaller you get, the more (DC) leakage current you get.  This is unused energy that leaks through the silicon.  This also depends on the physical size of the silicon die, and the number of die.  When memory die are stacked, the area is additive (DC power).  So an older 1MB flash die stacked 8 levels is much higher leakage current than 1 level 8MB die.

The larger consumer of energy is the voltage * current * frequency (AC) term.  This power consumption is around 75% on DRAM, but not sure what flash's ratio is, probably similar.

In terms of increasing power usually are idle, reads, column changes (DRAM), writes, refresh (DRAM), followed by erase (Flash).

Latest memories get very efficient when idle.  So the above 75% may currently be as high as 85% or more.  I haven't calculated or measured in a while, sorry.

SRAM only uses power per read or write.  Almost nothing the rest of the time.

Comment: what exactly is voltage * current * frequency (AT)? Power consumption is 75%on DRAM. 75% of what?

Comment: Sorry, brain f@rt. Correction:
Signalling power = Voltage^2 * current * frequency of data transfers.  This is the "AC" power consumption.  Changing external wires from 0 to 1 takes this type of current.
75% of the power consumption is the die when not in standby (DC current), the 25% is the signalling power (AC).  ie active DRAM, no traffic, is 75% of max power.

Comment: Sorry you answer is good but I still need clarifications.For external wire you mean external for controller like pin for example. Second clarifiction: 75% is the Max power is DC(like leakage)?

Comment: Inside a chip, with short thin wires you can wiggle at GHz for cheap.  Mostly because voltage inside is low (800mV) using 10's of uA.  On the outside, the voltage swing is higher, wires are longer, and current is higher due to impedance matching by receiver.  Memories have very few wires wiggling both inside and outside, so AC power is really small.  Yes 75% is 30% leakage and 45% gate power.

Comment: Also, the less outside wires a memory has even more power is saved

Comment: I would like to ask you technical question (again for flash) which is not quite for stack overflow. Is it OK to ask you in comments?

Comment: No reason why not to ask, puts all the answers in one place.  

I would like to revise leakage - Memory has lower leakage than CPUs/GPUs, because of larger geometry.  I don't know the exact numbers, but one should be able to dig those up.

Comment: I have to write a science article with a guy from univercity. In this article I pointed that: less code size mean less flash and that mean less cost of the device. The guy from univercity said that should be good to have another benefits other than the cost of the device. So I would like to ask you for any other benefits of using controller with less flash (other than the cost). If you know anything please describe in details.

Comment: But you know that programs always outgrow their memory capacity.  Remember original PC had 64KB.  Now some machines have 64GB.  My first tablet 1GB, can't run chrome any more.  My phone is 6GB, 1GB free.  Overall power consumption may be lower on new technologies, but I don't know for sure.  Cost is almost irrelevant after one year, as prices drop 30-50% for same capacity every year.

Answer (score 0):

Some clarifications:

1. dynamic power consumption  is proportional to `<data change frequency> x <Capacitance> x <Voltage^2>`, the C here stands for Capacitance, not Current. This is the dominant factor when you are performing a READ/WRITE/ERASE operation.
2. Leakage power is proportional to the area or the logic/SRAM/FLASH. This is the dominant factor when logic/SRAM/FLASH are IDLE.
3. communication with on chip SRAM is more power efficient than off-chip FLASH because you consume additional power in communication: the signal is driven through pad cells that typically operate at two to four times the voltage of standard logic. The capacitance of on board wires is several orders of magnitude higher than on-chip routing and the data needs to be copied several times to internal flops on the master and slave side of the FLASH interface to support the communication protocol and synchronize the signals. This means that SRAM access latency is lower than access to FLASH.
4. besides being cheaper, systems with flash are also modular - the same chip can be used on several boards with different FLASH sizes.
5. a FLASH block has a finite number of write/erase cycles it can support before it becomes unusable. Larger FLASH devices can spread write/erase operations over a larger set of memory blocks, resulting in longer effective lifetime and effective size.